# Spring security авторизация сразу после регистрации

Tags: java, spring, авторизация, spring-security

Привет) Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь сразу после того как зарегистрировался не перенаправлялся на страницу логина, а был сразу аунтефицирован, и мог перенаправиться на страницу /home , к примеру. пыталась вот как сделать:

```
 @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute @Validated User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {
//code
request.login(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
return "redirect:/home
}
```

В остальном код ничего особенного - обычный spring mvs+spring security; Вот конфиг configure(http)

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/register", "/like").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: а ваш код не работает? не происходит redirect или просить опять залогиниться? И у вас еще в  методе registerUser() в return "redirect:/home  не дописали закрывающий символ кавычки " и ;

Comment: @am233dmg с кавычками я скопировала криво. Нет, все работает, но вместо аторизации отправляет на страницу логина

Comment: дайте, знать если получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете посмотреть здесь про **auto-login**:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813028/auto-login-after-successful-registration
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-auto-login-user-after-registration